# javascript for loop every 1,2,3,4

Tags: javascript

Looping through an array of 30 elements and need to apply different styles every 1,2,3 and 4th time the loop iterates. How would i do that?

```
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {

}
```

Comment: I'm sure this must be a duplicate but I can't find one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    switch (i % 4) {
       case 0: ... ; break;
       case 1: ... ; break;
       case 2: ... ; break;
       case 3: ... ; break;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the elements with a counter and reset it everytime you hit the fourth item...

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    switch(count)
    {
        case 0:
            // 1stitem
            break;
        case 1:
            // 2nd item
            break;
        case 2:
            // 3rd item
            break;
        case 3:
            // 4th item
            count = 0;
            break;
    }

    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that does what I think you're looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/cCdJw/

You can use a function to figure out the n-th item, here we pass in a max value (in your case 4) to allow us to effectively reset to 0 again after each fourth item.  To find out more about modulus take a look at this wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

```
function nthItem(index, max) {
    // this will tell us which item the element is, given a maximum to repeat the nth modulus "loop" over.
    return index % max + 1;
}
```

We add 1 to the `index % max` to start our item count at 1 rather than 0.

```
var arr = ["hello", "hola", "molo", "halo", "tere", "bonjour", "ciao", "ola", "hej"];

for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    var n = nthItem(i, 4),
        cssClass,
        thisGreeting;

    switch(n) {
        case 1 : 
            cssClass = "greeting-1";
            break;
        case 2 : 
            cssClass = "greeting-2";
            break;
        case 3 : 
            cssClass = "greeting-3";
            break;
        case 4 : 
            cssClass = "greeting-4";                             
            break;
    }

    thisGreeting = document.createElement("div");
    thisGreeting.innerHTML = arr[i];
    thisGreeting.setAttribute("class", cssClass);
    document.getElementById("greetings").appendChild(thisGreeting);
}
```

In the above code we add a different css class to style each element in the array according to it's position.

It's important to know that you can do this programmatically with JavaScript, but its probably much better if you're working with modern browsers to do this with the n-th child pseudo class in CSS.  Take a a look here for more info on that:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions